# What causes 'You are not authorized to access this page' during create/edit of any menu?

Tags: 7, routes, users

I got a very odd error for "new" admin user on Drupal 7. There are a few admin users in this site but only the "new" one that is unable to create, edit or list links on any menu. The error message is like so:

> You are not authorized to access this page

But this new admin user has the same role as other admins.

Does anyone know what can causing this?

Comment: We cannot debug a site to which we don't have access. Listing all the possible causes, hoping to guess what happened, is not the purpose of a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you flush caches and rebuild permissions (from status page) and run cron. 
If these fail check if any custom module implements hook_node_access
A rogue Rule could also be the culprit

Comment: I really afraid of rebuild permission. Will this causes anything during and after the process?

Comment: The site currently has over 5000 permissions in use.